# Angularjs $on called twice

Tags: angularjs, events, event-handling, listener

So I have this situation where one `controller` is `emitting` the `event` and the other `controller` has the `listener`. Here is the code:

In `controller A`, I have this method:

```
$scope.process = function () {
    var taskName = 'process';
    $scope.$emit('process', taskName);
}
```

In `controller B`, I have this:

```
$rootScope.$on('process', function (event, taskName) {
    //Do something here
});
```

Now whenever I visit other pages on application and comeback to this, the `process` listener gets created twice. I cannot use `controller` scope as the `event` is getting `emitted` from other `controller`. How can I destroy listener once it has completed its task? I have also tried `$scope.$destroy()`. Doesn't really work. What is the correct way of doing this?

I am on `Angularjs 1.4.7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do it in different way:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast(...)
...
$scope.$on(...)
```

Then you do not need to unsubscribe.
If you really need for some reason to subscribe to $rootScope, then:

```
var deregister = $scope.$on(...);
...
deregister(); // destory that listener
```